# Ajax.BeginForm() InsertionMode.InsertBefore not working as expected

Tags: ajax, forms, dom, asp.net-mvc-5

Using Ajax.BeginForm i am trying to insert the content i get returned from my action. The action gets called and the correct elements get returned however the InsertionMode.InsertBefore does not work as expected.

**My view**

```
@model DynamicTable.Models.BtwViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.BtwShowList.First().Description)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.BtwShowList.First().Percentage)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.BtwShowList.First().Info)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in @Model.BtwShowList)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_BtwRow", item);
        }

        <tr  id="addRow" style="display:none"></tr>
        @using (@Ajax.BeginForm("InsertData",new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode= InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId="addRow" }))
        {         
            <tr >
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BtwToBeAdded.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BtwToBeAdded.Percentage, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BtwToBeAdded.Info, new { @class = "form-control col-md-10" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input value="Add" class="btn btn-default"  type="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

**My controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult InsertData(BtwViewModel btwViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var list = HttpContext.Session[SessionKey] as List<Btw>;
        list.Add(btwViewModel.BtwToBeAdded);
    }
    return PartialView("_BtwRow", btwViewModel.BtwToBeAdded);
}
```

**My partialview**

```
@model DynamicTable.Models.Btw
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Description</td>
    <td>@Model.Percentage</td>
    <td>@Model.Info</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I would expect the result of my partialview to be inserted before the  element that contains the id "addRow" however the result of my partialview gets inserted inside the tr element! :/

**This is the result i get now**

```
<tr id="addRow" style="display:none">
    <tr>
      <td>Stackoverflow</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>please help me</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

There are no javascript errors in console neither..
How can i fix my code so the result of my partialview gets inserted before the tr element with id addRow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use InsertMode.InsertBefore, it will insert the result of your ajax call, before the content (="innerHTML") of your 'addRow' element.

The solutions would be: place your form inside a  tag (so outside of the tbody), then give your  an ID, for example "table-results". Now update your AjaxOptions and set UpdateTargetId="table-results" and InsertMode = InsertMode.InsertAfter. Your ajax result will now be added to the bottom of your  rows, while your form stays at the bottom of your table.

Comment: I cann't able to see teh Destination attribute in MVC4 please lett me know what i am missing

Comment: Sorry I ment UpdateTargetId (updated the answer above)

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below

Note : Here I passed UpdateTargetId to  table body See clearly the difference between your and my code

```
<tbody id="addRow">
    @foreach (var item in @Model.BtwShowList)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_BtwRow", item);
    }

    <tr style="display:none"></tr>
```

It will automatically update the row before all rows.